# Publishing All users in meteor with enabled accounts package and disabled autopublish

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want publish all users collection to all my clients. I have removed the autopublish package and added the accounts package to the project. I know that the accounts package only publish the user collection to the logged in user, but i want send the complete users-collection.

Pub/Sub Code:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('users', function() {
    return Meteor.users.find();
  });
}
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe('users');
}
```

And here are the template that want present all users from mongodb:

```
Template.userList.helpers({
  users: function () {
    return Meteor.users.find(); 
  }
});
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The user collection is not published to the entirely clients, i have one user collection per logged in user.

Comment: Can you post you HTML template too?

Comment: <template name="userList">
    <h1> Logged in Users </h1>
    <ul>
      {{#each users}}
        {{username}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>

Comment: im using meteor 0.9.1

Comment: People have had some problems with 0.9.1, but I tried your code in a new Meteor 0.9.1 project, and everything worked for me (though, `{{username}}` should be `<li>{{username}}</li>`). Nothing else you can tell us about your code?

Comment: Your `Pub/Sub Code`, in which file (and folder) is it saved?

Comment: Ohhhh :) ok i saved it in client folder and therefore it is not served to my clients. Done thanks

Answer (score 2):

Following setup:
i have created meteor project and deleted the autopublish and insecure package and added the accounts-password package to my project.

Pub/Sub Code :

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('usersData', function() {
    return Meteor.users.find();
  });
}
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe('usersData');
}
```

Templates:

```
<template name="userList">
    <h1> Users </h1>
    <ul>
      {{#each usersList}}
        {{> userItem}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>

<template name="userItem">
  <li>{{username}}</li>
</template>
```

Template helper:

```
Template.userList.helpers({
  usersList: function () {
    return Meteor.users.find(); 
  }
});
```

Works.

Please refrain using a meteor predefined variable name such as users and avoid confusion during debugging process

Answer (score 0):

if (Meteor.isServer) {

```
 Meteor.publish(null, function() {
      return Meteor.users.find();
 });
```

}

This is appropriate way without even subscribing, it will publish all the user collectioin, 
but this isn't advisable.